# Selenium IDE - How to use regex with command "assert text"?

Tags: regex, selenium-ide

I try to check if a certain element contains the text with the value `40,00 €` or `40,00 Euro`.

**Attempt:**

```
regexp:40,00.+
```

[image: regexp:40,00.+]

**Output:**

*verifyText on css=.price:nth-child(2) with value regexp:40,00 Failed: Actual value "40,00 €" did not match "regexp:40,00.+"*

Comment: +(.*) perhaps..?

Comment: do you mean `regexp:40,00.+(.*)` ?

Comment: Yes. Either regexp:40,00.+(.*) (no space) or just regexp:40,00.(.*)

Comment: No, I get `Failed:
Actual value "40,00 €" did not match "regexp:40,00.(.*)"` I think regex is not supported anymore?

Comment: Are you sure the keyword is "regexp"? Perhaps try "regex", or skip "regexp" altogether? (put 40,00(.*) )